# putting files on a sub domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I registered a sub domain on my server using DNS: client.henrybuilt.com

If I wanted the default directory of client.henrybuilt.com to be /client/ on my ftp server, what would I do?

Basically I want it to be like a separate site when you visit client.henrybuilt.com

Apparently I should use .htaccess -> mod_rewrite but what would I do more specifically?

Comment: usually you do this from your hosts control panel. What host are you using?

Comment: I don't know about your hosting company but some do allow creating of a subdomain as a domain with a `DocumentRoot` of its own.

Comment: edited. gained ability to use .htaccess

Comment: You should ask that your hosting companies support, not us (and it is normally independent to .htaccess/mod_rewrite).

Comment: Your control panel should have dealt about which directory the sub domain points to, unless you didn't notice that at all when you setup your sub-domain.

Comment: there was no option. I am with crystaltech. it uses webcontrolcenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using apache you need to add a new virtualhost then you just need to change the document root in the virtualhost to the location of your files and then make that folder in the web root

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName client.henrybuilt.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/client/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/client/">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

put your files here - `/var/www/html/client/`